# MongoDB aggregation - filtering sub arrays and projecting part of their data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents that look like this one

Each document contains "books" and "movies" but I don't know how many of each.

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "books" : [
        {
            "title" : "Philosopher's Stone", 
            "PopularVote" : 10, 
            "CriticsVote" : 9 
        },
        {
            "title" : "Chamber of Secrets", 
            "PopularVote" : 8, 
            "CriticsVote" : 6 
        },
        {
            "title" : "Prisoner of Azkaban", 
            "PopularVote" : 2, 
            "CriticsVote" : 10 
        }
    ],
    "movies" : [
        {
            "title" : "Goblet of Fire", 
            "PopularVote" : 5, 
            "CriticsVote" : 10 
        },
        {
            "title" : "Order of the Phoenix", 
            "PopularVote" : 8, 
            "CriticsVote" : 9 
        }
    ]       
}
```

I want to select only the arrays that got a 10 on PopularVote OR CriticsVote and project only the title. The result should look like this.

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "books" : [
        {
            "title" : "Philosopher's Stone",  
        },
        {
            "title" : "Prisoner of Azkaban",  
        }
    ],
    "movies" : [
        {
            "title" : "Goblet of Fire", 
        }
    ]       
}
```

I tried all kind of combinations of `$filter` and `cond`: but failed.

Thanks!

p.s. Harry potter fans, this is just a data example that doesn't reflect my opinions on the books and movies (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to replace existing `books` and `movies` with filtering condition applied and then you can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to get only titles, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            books: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$books",
                    as: "b",
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            { $eq: [ "$$b.PopularVote", 10 ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$$b.CriticsVote", 10 ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            movies: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$movies",
                    as: "m",
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            { $eq: [ "$$m.PopularVote", 10 ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$$m.CriticsVote", 10 ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "books.title": 1,
            "movies.title": 1
        }
    }
])
```